# selenium page object model: waiting for java script to complete

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, paypal-sandbox

I'm using the selenium page object model to test a website. We have access to the sandbox PayPal account which allows us place test PayPal orders with a mock account.

My problem is on the sandbox PayPal login screen when I click login with the account I have created some java script (I'm guessing) displays an animation saying "Authenticating your information Logging you in"

When this happens my page fails because the is loaded() is expecting the url to be different but because the page doesn't start to load the next page until after this javascript completes the url is not correct.

I could stick a hardcoded wait for this login to take effect but does anybody know a better / proper way to handle this?

Comment: What about just waiting for the streamer on that page to go away?

Comment: For the time being I've put a loop that checks for an element on the next page. It loops around upto five minutes until the element is displayed then breaks out. This works but I would have thought there was a better way?

Comment: In your PageObject, at the end of your login method, just put in a wait for the animation to go away.